# module.js:340 throw err cannot find module articleprovider-mongodb.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've uninstalled and reinstalled it three times and cleared the cache, but it's still not finding this file. 
I tried creating an articleprovider-mongodb.js file from one I found online, but no joy. Here's my error message:

```
module.js:340                                                                                                   
throw err;                                                                                                  
      ^                                                                                                     
Error: Cannot find module './articleprovider-mongodb.js'                                                        
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)                                                      
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)                                                                 
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)                                                                        
at require (module.js:380:17)                                                                               
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/action/blog/app.js:6:23)                                                       
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)                                                                       
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)                                                         
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)                                                                           
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)                                                                 
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Comment: Installed what? You seem to be following this [blog post](http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb). Or some variant of it. You do not say what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I figured it out; the download for mongo hadn't gone through properly or something. Once I created a new nitrous box and redownloaded everything, it worked. Don't ask me why.

Answer (score 0):

When I created a new nitrous box and redownloaded everything (and I mean everything--stylus, express, mongo, etc) it worked. Don't ask me how or why, I'm just going with it.